# How to put a subscript in a superscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

How can I write the following thing?

`a^(b_c)`, `b` being a superscript of `a`, and `c` being a subscript of `b`.

Comment: try `a^{b_c}`, note `{ }`, not `( )`... Welcome to the group!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: If you have more questions like this, consider reading one of the books listed here: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

Comment: do you mind if we close this as too localized?

Comment: @cmhughes Why should this be too localized? Easy (from the point of view of an experienced user) ≠ too localized. This may very well end up a very popular question.

Comment: @doncherry if you feel that it is a good question, feel free to up vote it and post an answer

Comment: @ cmhughes I do not mind at all, up to you.

Comment: @cmhughes I had forgotten to upvote, but did now, even though it’s questionable because of the “shows research effort” requirement. I’m not really inclined to post an answer because I don’t use math mode at all; I think it’d be better if one of the many people who know their way around these areas posted an answer.

Comment: In general, I would say that having sub-/superscripts within sub-/superscripts is quite bad practice. You might consider refactoring your text to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
a^{b_c}
```

note that I have used `{}` instead of `()`.

Your question is perfectly reasonable- for further reading, you might like to look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

Answer (score 0):

```
a^{\left(b_c\right)}
```

Note that the curly brackets `{}` are used in latex to set delimiters on the preceding operator (in this case `^`). The variable size brackets enclose the text, although it's not clear from what you wrote if you want these in the final setting. An alternative is `a^{b_c}` or `a^{b_{c}}`, although the curly braces are implicit and not needed for a single expression. If you wanted, you could write: `a^{b_{c^{d_e}}}`, which would look weird, but be valid.

Comment: There is no reason to use `\left ... \right` here. Other than  that, good explanation.